# ajax call to controller method fails with UnauthorizedAccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I've got an MVC app using knockout.  In my view model, I have an ajax call to a controller method returning a list of records from a database.  That call succeeds without issue.  But to edit a particular record I have another ajax call to a different method on the same controller which never reaches the method, instead returning status code 302.  The response header shows "/WebUI/System/Account/UnauthorizedAccess".  The controller is decorated with the Authorize attribute.  If I decorate the method that is failing with AllowAnnonymous() then all is well.  Unfortunately, we don't want to leave that on the method.

Here's my viewModel:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
function BranchViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.BranchID = ko.observable("");
  self.BranchNum = ko.observable("");
  self.BranchName = ko.observable("");

  var branch = {
    BranchID: self.BranchID,
    BranchNum: self.BranchNum,
    BranchName: self.BranchName,
  };

  self.branch = ko.observable();
  self.branches = ko.observableArray();

  $.ajax({
    url: "GetBranches",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
      self.branches(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    }
  });

  self.edit = function (branch) {
    self.branch(branch);
  }

  // Update details
  self.update = function () {
    var editedBranch = self.branch();
    $.ajax({
      url: "UpdateBranch",
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: ko.toJSON(editedBranch),
      success: function (data) {
        self.branches.removeAll();
        self.branches(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
        self.branch(null);
      }
    })
      .fail(
      function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
        alert(err);
      });
  }
}

var viewModel = new BranchViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And here are the methods in the controller.  GetBranches works fine.  UpdateBranch, not so much.

```
Public Function GetBranches() As JsonResult
  Using modelContext As New Repository(ConnectionInformation.GetSQLConnectionString)
    Dim data = modelContext.Branch.ToList()
    Return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
  End Using
End Function
Public Function UpdateBranch(item As Branch) As JsonResult
  Using modelContext As New Repository(ConnectionInformation.GetSQLConnectionString)
    Dim branch = modelContext.Branch.Single(Function(x) x.BranchID = item.BranchID)
    If branch IsNot Nothing Then
      branch.BranchNum = item.BranchNum
      branch.BranchName = item.BranchName
      modelContext.SaveChanges()
      Dim data = modelContext.Branch.ToList()
      Return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End If
  End Using

  Return Json("")
End Function
```

Here is the network info:

Request URL: xxxx://localhost/WebUI/System/Branch/UpdateBranch
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Content-Length:480
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 04 Aug 2017 12:33:06 GMT
Expires:-1
Location:/WebUI/System/Account/UnauthorizedAccess
Pragma:no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options:NOSNIFF
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge;
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:120
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:Menu-0=,35; Menu-80=,35; ASP.NET_SessionId=fj0txxxxx2j13extb25ksmfl0; 
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/WebUI/System/Branch/Index
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Is there something inherently different between the call to retrieve the list of records and the call to update? I suspect this might be something simple that I am just overlooking.

Comment: maybe your user does not have permissions to edit the record

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using?

Comment: It's a custom scheme, but we have implemented a custom Authorize attribute based on a UserInfo object which is part of it.

Comment: Continuing my comment(I hit return too soon)  the UserInfo object contains a "IsUserLoggedIn" property.  Your question prompted me to dig a little deeper.  On the call to GetBranch, the UserInfo.IsUserLoggedIn property is true.  On the call to UpdateBranch, it is false, hence the Unauthorized status.  We seem to have a scope issue.

Comment: Strangely enough, another developer ran the same code on his machine and everything worked as expected.  No need for AllowAnnoymous attribute.  Baffled what is different.